# Firestore Security Rules get Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Im using Cloud Firestore and im trying to create the security rules.
Now I ran into this Problem: 
I have a function to get the user data (which is stored in "/user_data")

```
function getUserData() {
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/user_data/$(request.auth.uid)).data;
}
```

And a dummy function to use this data

```
function doStuff() {
   return getUserData() == null || getUserData() != null;
}
```

When I run it (with authenticated user - with user document)
It just always returns false

Anyone can help?

Comment: What is your exact goal? To check if the document at `user_data/$(request.auth.uid)`exists? Or that a specific field of this document has as specific value? `data` returns a "map of the document data" and therefore I am not clear on what you want to check with `getUserData() == null` or `getUserData() != null`.

Comment: I try to check if a list contains a specific value. Since that always fails I wondering if I even got the data. Then I built this dummy function to test and I don't know how to get / use the data map.

Comment: What is the name of this field?

Comment: You can get the value of field by doing `data.fieldName`, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents

Comment: The name is ownedLists and I want to know if a specific string is in there

Comment: I know how to get the field value in theory. It just always fails when I test it and I think that is because I do not really get the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick (untested):

```
function getOwnedLists() {
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/user_data/$(request.auth.uid)).data.ownedLists;
}

function checkValueIsIn(valueToCheck) {
   return valueToCheck in getOwnedLists();
}
```

---

Based on the following documentation:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource.html#data
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map.html

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. I already tried something like that but it did not work. This does not work either. Maybe the error is somewhere else. Are there any perquisites needed (that I might have forgotten) so this can work?

Comment: I just tried again and it worked. It must have been a typo somewhere. Thanks a lot for the fast response